# Is there any JSON response size limitation?

Tags: json, angular, spring, rest, google-chrome

Hi am trying to send about 66.7 MB of compressed (599 uncompressed) of json data from java rest API. However at Angular(7) am getting response as

null. If I try same API with less data it works fine. Data being sent is byte array.Please find below snapshots for request ,response. Is there any workaround /or limitation. ?[image][image]

Comment: Is there any error in the log files ? If yes please add it to the problem.

Comment: What do you send the data as? `multipart/form-data`? If so, you may need to increase the maximum allowed request size, since the default is [10MB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartProperties.html#:~:text=max%2Drequest%2Dsize%20specifies%20the,The%20default%20is%2010MB.)

Comment: +1 for adding any exception from server log files. Additionally, can you update question with Response (status and all headers) from Firefox network panel (just like you have provided for request). The problem is either at server end (most likely) OR it is at angular end (not being able to handle such a large response data). Please update your question with relevant data points for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem. It seems since Chrome 80 there is a regression.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1097457&q=unexpected%20end%20of%20json%20input&can=2